# Center Div Content Within Responsive Layout

Tags: html, css, responsive

I'd like to have the content block centered horizontally within its outer div. I'm also trying to get the div content blocks to center horizontally when they begin to stack on smaller screens. Right now, when the columns stack, they're left-justified. I didn't have any luck with flex.
Working example below;

```css
body {
  background: #ccc;
} 
 
.spechighlights {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: #343434;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.spectable {
  width: 100%; 
  max-width: 900px; 
  background-color: #FFF; 
  border: 1px solid #d1d1d1; 
  padding: 48px; 
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}

.datacell {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  max-width: 390px;
  float: left;
} 
 
.datainside {
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 195px;
  float: left;
  font-weight: 300;
}
 
.datainside2 {
  width: 40%;
  max-width: 145px;
  float: left;
  font-weight: 300;
}
 
.datainside3 {
  width: 60%;
  max-width: 245px;
  float: left;
  font-weight: 300;
}   

div.datacell.spec {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  color: #616161;
  font-size: 15px;
}
 
div.datainside.medium {
  font-weight: 500;
}

div.datainside2.medium {
  font-weight: 500;
} 

hr {
  background-color:#c0c0c0; 
  width: 100%; 
  margin: 35px 0 8px 0; 
  clear: both;
} 

@media all and (max-width:960px){ 
  .datacell {
    width: 100%; 
    float: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div style="max-width:1000px; width:95%; margin:0 auto; overflow:hidden;">
  <div class="spectable">
    <h3 class="tabletitle">Title</h3>
    <div class="datacell spec">
      <div class="datainside medium">Length Overall</div>
      <div class="datainside">13.13M / 43' 1"</div>
      <hr style="margin-top:30px;">
      <div class="datainside medium">Beam</div>
      <div class="datainside">3.3M / 10' 10"</div>
      <hr>
      <div class="datainside medium">Draft</div>
      <div class="datainside">1.0M / 3' 3"</div>
      <hr>
    </div>
    <div class="datacell spec">
      <div class="datainside2 medium">Gas Power</div>
      <div class="datainside3">2 x 662HP Mercury Racing With NXT  Drives</div>
      <hr style="margin-top:30px;">
      <div class="datainside2 medium">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="datainside3">2 x 430HP Mercruiser 8.2 MAG H.O. ECT</div>
      <hr> 
    </div>

    <p style="clear:both; padding-top:15px;">
      <a href="#">Specs</a>
      &nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <a href="#">Color Options</a>   
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, but what is the problem?

Comment: Was not centering correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is not good. You should use the definition [CSS list](https://www.web4college.com/css/css_list_style.php) for this purpose with the padding and border properties.
I have solved it for you. I have made changes to your code to make it more friendly. But for media query you have to work.

Here is the link to [center div within a page or another div](https://www.web4college.com/questions/css-vertical-center-methods.php).

The following is the code that i have changed for you. There were many issues there i can't describe it here.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {background:#ccc;} 

.spechighlights {
font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
font-size: 50px;
line-height:50px;
color:#343434;
text-transform:uppercase;
}


.spectable {
width:100%; 
max-width:900px; 
background-color:#FFF; 
border: 1px solid #d1d1d1; 
padding:48px; 
margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
float:left;}

.datacellL {
width:40%;
display:inline-block;
margin-bottom:10px;
max-width:300px;
float:left;} 

.datacellR {
width:60%;
display:inline-block;
margin-bottom:10px;
max-width:480px;
float:left;}    

.datainside {
width:50%;
max-width:195px;
float:left;
font-weight:300;
padding:10px 0px;
border-bottom:2px solid rgba(200,200,200,1);}

.datainside2 {
width:35%;
max-width:100px;
float:left;
font-weight:300;
padding:10px 0px;
border-bottom:2px solid rgba(200,200,200,1);
}

.datainside3 {
width:65%;
max-width:300px;
float:left;
font-weight:300;
padding:10px 0px;
border-bottom:2px solid rgba(200,200,200,1);}           

div.datacell.spec {
font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
color:#616161;
font-size:15px;
}

div.datainside.medium {font-weight:500;}
div.datainside2.medium {font-weight:500;}   

hr {
background-color:#c0c0c0; 
width:100%; 
margin:35px 0 8px 0; 
clear:both;}    


@media all and (max-width:960px){   


.datacell {
width:100%; 
float:none;}}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div style="max-width:1250px; width:95%; margin:0 auto; overflow:hidden;">


<div class="spectable">
<h3 class="tabletitle">Title</h3>


<div class="datacellL spec">
<div class="datainside medium">Length Overall</div>
 <div class="datainside">13.13M / 43' 1"</div>

<div class="datainside medium">Beam</div>
<div class="datainside">3.3M / 10' 10"</div>

<div class="datainside medium">Draft</div>
<div class="datainside">1.0M / 3' 3"</div>

</div>

<div class="datacellR spec">
<div class="datainside2 medium">Gas Power</div>
<div class="datainside3">2 x 662HP Mercury Racing With NXT  Drives</div>

<div class="datainside2 medium">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="datainside3">2 x 430HP Mercruiser 8.2 MAG H.O. ECT</div>
</div>



<p style="clear:both; padding-top:15px;"><a href="#">Specs</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#">Color Options</a>   </p>
</div>
</div> 

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Through some more experimenting, I simply added "text-align:center" to the ".spectable" class, which is the overall container and then within each inside Div, I added "text-align:left". This kept the div's centered when they stacked and the text left-justified.

Answer (score -1):

For centerd horizontally, if the child is a inline element, use `text-align: center`., if the child is a block element, use `margin: 0 auto`. That is the main points.

Wish this can help you.